# How to replace "," with ", " and saving the previous text?

Tags: replace

I want to replace all occurrences in a text with ","

for example

```
"word1,word2,word3"
```

became

```
"word1, word2, word3"
```

this one is bad

```
:%s/,/, /g
```

because

```
"word1,word2,word3, word4"
```

became (note the double white space)

```
"word1, word2, word3,  word4"
```

This one delete the next letter

```
:%s/,[a-z]/, /gc

word1,word2...
```

became

```
word1, ord2
```

How to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> sed -i 's/,/, /g; s/,\s\+/, /g'
> ```

You can use the exact same logic directly in Vim:

```
:%s/,/, /g
:%s/,\s\+/, /g
```

In general, I think doing things in *n* smaller and more intuitive steps is more efficient than wasting hours figuring out a smart and more elegant one-liner… but this is not such a case.

The following does what you want in a single take:

```
:%s/,\s*/, /g
```

The pattern matches:

- a single comma, `,`,
- followed by *zero or more* whitespace characters, as many as possible, `\s*`,

witch covers `,` (because there is zero whitespace after the comma), and any variant of `,` , `,`        , etc.

See `:help /*`.

Answer (score 6):

While I'd do it exactly like in [romainl's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/43656/4866), let me point out a few pattern tricks that can make your life easier.

Your almost-solution
`:%s/,[a-z]/, /gc`
can be turned into a working solution by ending the match after the comma using the `\ze` (end match) atom like this

```
:%s/,\ze[a-z]/, /gc
```

This will exclude the letter following the comma from being part of the match. This is explained in `:help /\ze`. (Also see `:help /\zs` for the start match atom.)

To allow for words starting with capital letters, consider using `,\ze\S` or `,\ze\w` which will match non-whitespace or *word* characters, respectively. See `:help /\S` and `:help /\w`.

As I initially said, romainl's solution is perfect for this example. For more complex problems, these often come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using captures

```
:%s/,\(\w\)/, \1/g
```

Search for a `,`, capture a word character, replace with a `,`  followed by that same captured word character `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this workaround works, but using external command

```
:! sed 's/,/, /g; s/,\s\+/, /g'
```

Comment: This solution would work in Vim as well...  So why not make this a proper Vim answer?

Comment: It would be better to write `:[range]!sed <sed script>` and let sed filter the input.

Comment: Wouldn't `sed -i` need an input file, like a `%` appended to the line?

Comment: Thanks I have correct it.